# ggplot2 scatter plot with FIXED LOG axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to get a R plot with log-scale axes and fixed equal breaks on x and y. I transform the axes into log scale using the following code.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(cars*1000, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point() + 
scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                   labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

[image: which gives me this]

Now I want the x and y limits and ticks to be exactly the same from 0 to 10^5. I tried  `p + coord_fixed()` and `p + coord_equal()` but it does not give me the same scaling.

Comment: Set `limits` inside `scale_*_log10` to be the same for both axes, then `coord_fixed` should work

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't seem to work. Just tried it in the following code and it returns an empty plot:

ggplot(cars*1000, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point() + 
scale_x_log10(limits=c(0,10^5),breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
scale_y_log10(limits=c(0,10^5),breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                   labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+geom_point()

Comment: Just changed limits to c(1,10^5) and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(cars*1000, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), 
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)), 
                limits = c(10^0, 10^5)) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)),
                limits = c(10^0, 10^5)) 
p
```

[image]